# PHP session variables lost on header redirect using PHP_SELF in the form action

Tags: php, forms, session, cookies, redirect

I have a multi-step form, let's say for the sake of ease it's 2 steps.  First step I want to select a radio button and based on that radio button selection it takes me to a certain page, but I also want that selection stored in a session.  I have 2 pages:
page1.php

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['post'])) {
if (($_POST['country'] == 'US')) {
header("Location: US_Products.php"); }
elseif (($_POST['country'] == 'CDN')) {
header("Location: CDN_Products.php"); }
else { die("Error"); }
exit;
}
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<label for="USA">USA:</label>
<input type="radio" name="country" value="US">
<label for="CDN">Canada:</label>
<input type="radio" name="country" value="CDN">
<input type="submit" name="post" value="Go To Filter">
</form>
```

Page2.php (either A or B)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'];
<?php echo $_SESSION['country']; ?>
```

The Country choice is not being passed when I have it do this conditional redirect.  Is there a problem with session variables and redirects or session variables and PHP_SELF or something?

Comment: Session variables are transferred fine, but the POST variables are not. Sending a Location header doesn't send any POST data.

Comment: What method could I use to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 1:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['post'])) {
    $_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'];
    if (($_POST['country'] == 'US')) {
        header("Location: US_Products.php"); }
    elseif (($_POST['country'] == 'CDN')) {
        header("Location: CDN_Products.php"); }
    else { die("Error"); }
    exit;
}
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<label for="USA">USA:</label>
<input type="radio" name="country" value="US">
<label for="CDN">Canada:</label>
<input type="radio" name="country" value="CDN">
<input type="submit" name="post" value="Go To Filter">
</form>
```

Page 2:

```
session_start();
<?php echo $_SESSION['country']; ?>
```

Or using include method, just use one page:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['post'])) {
    if (($_POST['country'] == 'US')) {
        include("US_Products.php"); }
    elseif (($_POST['country'] == 'CDN')) {
        include("CDN_Products.php"); }
    else { die("Error"); }
    exit;
}
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<label for="USA">USA:</label>
<input type="radio" name="country" value="US">
<label for="CDN">Canada:</label>
<input type="radio" name="country" value="CDN">
<input type="submit" name="post" value="Go To Filter">
</form>
```

and you should be able to use `echo $_POST['country']` on US_Products.php and CDN_Products.php, or

Comment: YOU ROCK!!!  So defining it on the second page was screwing it up?  This might be a stupid question, but do you always define session variables to POST variables on the page where the POST is input?

Comment: once you call `header`, you've lost your `$_GET` and `$_POST` data because you've gone to another page.  So your options are to store it in a session variable before calling header, or pass the data through the header call by doing something like `header("Location: US_Products.php?country=$_POST[country]");`, which would make `country` available in the `$_GET` array of US_Products.php

Answer (score 0):

Set the session variable *before* you redirect - the post is lost, as the redirect is essentially a regular GET request

```
if (($_POST['country'] == 'US')) 
{
  $_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'];
  header("Location: US_Products.php"); 
}
elseif (($_POST['country'] == 'CDN')) 
{
  $_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'];
  header("Location: CDN_Products.php"); 
}
else 
{ 
  die("Error"); 
}
```