# Undefined index when using $_POST superglobal

Tags: php

I am having a conceptual problem with superglobal `$_POST`.
It is supposed to be available at all times without needing any declaration.

I have three simple scripts:

---

**Script 1 – home.php**

```
<?php
SESSION_START();
?>
<html> <head> <title>Home</title> </head>
<body>
<!-- this form will pass $_POST["pd"] to check.php -->
<form name="input" action="check.php" method="post"> 
<input type="password" name="pd" size="15" maxlength="14">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body> 
</html> 
?>
```

---

**Script 2 – check.php**

```
<?php
SESSION_START();
if ($_POST["pd"] == "hello") 
{    header( 'Location: http://127.0.0.1/PP/ok.php' ) ;  }
?>
```

---

**Script 3 – ok.php**

```
<?php
SESSION_START();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
echo $key;
echo " = ";
echo $value;
}
echo "password = ".$_POST["pd"];
?>

<html> <head> <title>PasswordOK</title> </head>
 <body>
   Password OK
 </body>
</html>
```

---

Script 1: displays a form where I enter the password `hello` and submit it to script 2.

Script 2: checks superglobal `$_POST["pd"] == "hello"` and since it is correct it sends me to script 3. It does NOT give an `Undefined index` error.

Script 3: the `foreach` loop should access `$_POST["pd"]` superglobal and display `pd = hello`. It doesn’t display anything – and it doesn’t give me the `Undefined index` error.

`echo "password = ".$_POST["pd"];` should display `password = hello`. It displays `password =` and displays the `Undefined index` error.

The HTML block functions properly and displays the date and message.

---

Here’s my problem.

Since `$_POST["pd"]` is a superglobal it should never give rise to `Undefined index` error.
So why does it???
Many of your answers say that I should check that `$_POST["pd"]` actually exists – but I don’t have to do that for Script 2, so why should I have to do that for Script 3?

Am I missing something?

Is `$_POST["pd"]` a superglobal or isn’t it? And if it is then why does it ever give an `Undefined index` error?

Could anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's always available. That doesn't mean that it'll always have the exact contents you want.

Comment: You are just relocating the user from script2 to 3, not actually sending a valid POST request, are you?

Comment: Form inputs are not copied along when doing a redirect.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935359/php-session-variables-lost-on-header-redirect-using-php-self-in-the-form-action

Comment: sending to header( 'Location: http://127.0.0.1/PP/ok.php' ) does not contain your previously posted data thats why we call HTTP a stateless protocol and use session to use data from one page to another

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Pass POST variables with header()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447211/php-pass-post-variables-with-header)

Answer (score 2):

The `header(...)` line tells the browser to **navigate away from `check.php`** towards `ok.php`. The browser will issue a `GET` request this time and `$_POST` won't be available anymore.

To get a better understanding of what's going on, take a look at the Network tab in your browsers web inspector.

---

That said, to give more closure to your problem and maybe provide a solution, consider that:

> If you absolutely need to redirect (i.e. need to call `header`) and cannot `include` or `require`, then you might store the var in the session: $_SESSION['pd'] = $_POST['pd'].
>
> HTTP protocol has no state, that's why you have sessions and cookies at your disposal.

Comment: This is the right answer, you can't redirect POST data. You either need to convert posted data to get and append to the URL you are redirecting to or refactor your code so that the redirect is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending the `$_POST` from script2 to script3. Also your `$_SESSION` is useless if you never use it. You could put the post variable in a session and then it is accessible in script3.

Script2:
`$_SESSION['pd'] = $_POST['pd'];`

Script3
`echo $_SESSION['pd'];`

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is:

1. GET request for script1
2. POST request to script2 through form
3. Redirect response
4. GET request to script3

The form POSTs to script2, the posted data is available in `$_POST` only in this request, in script2. That script doesn't do much with that data and doesn't save it anywhere, instead it redirects the client to another script. The client does a whole new request to script3. script3 does not have access to the POST data POSTed to the previous script, because it's a completely new request.

It doesn't have anything to do with superglobals.